# Where the microsoft.office.tools.excel.dll is installed?

Tags: c#

I have installed VS2010 SP1 with .NET 4.0 and cannot find where the microsoft.office.tools.excel.dll is located.

Question> Where I can find this DLL?

Answer (score 6):

Normally this assembly should be in the GAC once you install the [Office Primary Interop Assemblies assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx). On my computer the assembly is located in:

```
c:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\VSTO40\v4.0.Framework\
```

And here's the [corresponding article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh3965hw.aspx) about installing those assemblies.

Comment: In my `c:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft` directory I only have `Framework/` and `IIS/`