# How do you install Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, com, nuget

I am trying to get a C# Windows Forms project running in

However, I am getting the following exception on this line:

```
xlApp = new ExcelApi.Application();
```

[image: 00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046]

After doing some investigation, I noticed that one of the references is not properly installed. It shows a yellow triangle next to the name. However I cannot for the life of me figure out how to install this package. I've tried **Adding Reference** and using Nuget but the package does not appear anywhere and there are no download sources online.

[image: microsoft.office.tools.excel]

Does anyone have any idea how I can get this to work?

---

**Version info:**

- Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.6.4
- Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.7.03.062

Comment: I do not ... is that necessary? As you can see in my screenshot I have `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` installed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where the microsoft.office.tools.excel.dll is installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190667/where-the-microsoft-office-tools-excel-dll-is-installed)

Comment: @RyanWilson Knowing the install path won't necessarily fix OP's issue. I don't think that's a duplicate.

Comment: probably related: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/configuring-a-computer-to-develop-office-solutions?view=vs-2019

Comment: @LewsTherin No, but if they don't have it installed there is no way to solve the broken reference, so it's the logical place to start.

Comment: @RyanWilson True, but that still doesn't make it a duplicate question.

Comment: @CodyBugstein, hi, this Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.v9.0.dll is not required and you can remove it. For your development requirement, please try to install the Office.

Answer (score 1):

1. Close any instances of Visual Studio you have open
2. Run the Visual Studio Installer (search for it, or it is most commonly in `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\`)
3. Click the **Modify** button (or **More > Modify**)
   [image: modify button]
4. Verify you have the **Office/SharePoint development** workload checked
5. If it's not checked, check it
6. Make sure that **Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO)** under the **Optional** section is also checked
   [image]
7. Click the **Modify** button

Comment: I don't have Office installed. So I do need Office installed? But it costs money